# passing hindi message in sms api not working from java

Tags: java

I am passing hindi in sms variable but at mobile sms, it's showing special character like ऩ
I used utf-8 and utf-16 but not get success.

```
String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(sms, "UTF-16");
```

Please suggest thanks in advance.

Comment: Is SMS API accept hindi chars?

Comment: What API? What does its documentation say about non-ASCII characters?

Comment: special character like '#&1234;'

Comment: In Java, that would be `\u1234`, and **not** `#&1234;`. Anyway, if the API doesn't take those symbols, it won't help you.

Comment: @asif may I know how did u solved above issue